# Convergence of Random Series; Determine Limit Infimum

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(Y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be independent random variables such that $P(Y_{n} = n - 1) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $P(Y_{n} = - 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Check that $E[Y_{n}] = 0$ and $X_n := \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{n}$ is a martingale. I would like to determine $\liminf X_{n}$ and $\limsup X_{n}$.

By second Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have $$P(Y_{n} = n-1 \text{ i.o.}) = 1 = P(Y_{n} = -1 \text{ i.o.}).$$ The following argument shows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_{n} = + \infty$ a.s. Let $T_{0} \equiv 1$ and $T_{k} = \inf\{ n > T_{k-1} : Y_{n} = n - 1\}$. Check that $T_{k}$ are a.s. finite (strictly increasing) stopping times, and that
    $$
  X_{T_{1}} = Y_{1} + \dots + Y_{T_{1} - 1} + Y_{T_{1}} = 1 = T_{0},
 $$
    because $Y_{1} \equiv 0, Y_2 = \dots = Y_{T_{1} - 1} = - 1$ and $Y_{T_{1}} = T_{1} - 1$. Inductively, we can observe that
    $$
  X_{T_{2}} = X_{T_{1}} + (X_{T_{2}} - X_{T_{1}}) =  T_{0} + T_{1}
 $$
    and 
    $$
  X_{T_{n}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T_{n} \geq n
 $$
    since $T_{k}$ is strictly increasing and $T_{0} = 1$. It follows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_{n} = + \infty$ a.s.

But it is unclear to me if $\liminf_{n} X_{n} = + \infty$ or $\liminf_{n} X_{n} = - \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It is $- \infty$. To see it, note that this is a renewal process, so every time you hit the $n+1$, now, you have a positive chance of getting $2n$ of $-1$s one after another ($(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{2n} $ has a limit of $e^{-2}$). By Borel Cantelli, this will happen infinitely many times, so you will reach arbitrarily small numbers almost surely.

Comment: I agree with your intuition, but I have the following two concerns: 1) notice that each upward jump, despite with small probability, has a large magnitude. As a result of this magnitude, we have $X_{T_{n}} \geq n$. To return to the same negative level, we need to take more consecutive $-1$'s. To really control the probability, it seems that we need some upper bound on $X_{T_{n}}$, which is not clear to me. 2) When you say "renewal process", do you mean something like strong Markov property, i.e. Markov property applying to stopping times?